# Join on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 SQL tables:

```
select * from operation;
id |        name
----+--------------------
1 | Account add
2 | Account edit

 select * from role_operation;
 id |   role   | operation
----+----------+-----------
  1 | admin    |        1
  2 | operator |        1
  3 | admin    |        2
```

The `id` column in operation table and the `operation` column in role_operation are linked. (Foreign key). How can I get all rows where operation `name = Account add`

I tried `SELECT role_operation.role, operation.name FROM role_operation INNER JOIN operation ON role_operation.operation=operation.id;`

But this gives me all the rows which have an operation id present in the operation  field of role_operation table.

Comment: You forgot the WHERE clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use where

```
SELECT role_operation.role, operation.name 
FROM role_operation 
INNER JOIN operation ON role_operation.operation=operation.id
where  operation.name = 'Account add';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT role_operation.role, operation.name FROM role_operation
INNER JOIN operation on operation.id = role_operation.operation
WHERE operation.name='Account add'
```

Comment: please add some text explaining how/why your solution works.